# Equality of 2 Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading a book that states "If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then $X=Y$ if and only if, for all $x, x\in X$ if and only if $x\in Y$."

Perhaps it's because I learned the equality of two sets being defined as each one being a subset of the other (which makes perfect sense to me but perhaps that's just because it's had time to), but this definition does not strike me as true; couldn't there exist some $y\in Y$ such that $y\notin X$ and thus the two sets are not equivalent?

Also, I apologize for any mistakes in the writing of my math; I'm still getting used to this site.

Comment: definition of subset is $X\subseteq Y:\forall_xx\in X\rightarrow x\in Y$.  so just apply both ways and is true.

Comment: Haha you were the only one that immediately understood where my misunderstanding was; thank you!

Comment: If $X=Y$ then $X$ and $Y$ are somehow labels of the same mathematical object. Then expression $x\in X$ has automatically the same meaning as $x\in Y$. Only the "if" side is interesting here. It says that two sets $X$ and $Y$ are equal if they have the same elements.That is the axiom of extensionality. You could equivalently say that sets are completely determined by their elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is the same as $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$. Notice that $X \subseteq Y$ iff $\forall z(z\in X \rightarrow z\in Y)$, so $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$ iff $\forall z(z\in X \rightarrow z\in Y \text{ and } z\in Y \rightarrow z\in X)$ iff $\forall z(z\in X \leftrightarrow z\in Y)$ iff $X=Y$ by definition.

Comment: Oh yes thank you. I got confused by the IFF. I'm used to seeing it with the arrows (which I know means single arrow (implies) and single arrow (implies)) and thus thought it only went one way. Makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The two definitions really are saying the same thing. And not even in one of those weird ways where two things are equivalent but don't sound at all related. Like the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.

For a proof by contradiction, let's suppose your definition of equal sets ($X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$) holds while the new definition you have is not true. Then we'd have some sets $A,B$ such that $A \subseteq B, B\subseteq A$ but at least one $b \in B$ where $b \notin A$. Since $b \notin A$ and $b \in B$, $B$ cannot be a subset of $A$; to be a subset of $A$ would require that every element of $B$ is contained in $A$. Contradiction. Therefore the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. If you'll see my comment on the other question, my confusion was simply that I forgot IFF meant a double arrow which means that it goes "both ways" so to speak. I thought it was only saying that x has to belong to y; not the other way around. Now I see that it says both.